# firebase crashlytics ios build failed

Tags: ios, flutter, crashlytics

Describe the bug

```
Add firebase crashlytics dependencies and try running in ios device but fails with output:
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/jeremydormevil/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-2.2.5/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.m:17:9: fatal error: 'FIRCLSAnalyticsManager.h' file not found
#import "FIRCLSAnalyticsManager.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
/Users/jeremydormevil/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-2.2.5/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.m:17:9: fatal error: 'FIRCLSAnalyticsManager.h' file not found
#import "FIRCLSAnalyticsManager.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in parallel
```

Steps to reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Use firebase_crashlytics: ^2.2.5
Build app in IOS device
See error or incorrect behavior